# OpenCL device not working due to faulty path

Tags: radeon, opencl

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 and have an AMD Radeon RX 580. I installed the latest open-source drivers (amdgpu-pro-21.30-1290604-ubuntu-20.04) with
`./amdgpu-install -y --opencl=rocr,legacy`.

Now, `clinfo -l` prints

```
Platform #0: Clover
 `-- Device #0: Radeon RX 580 Series (POLARIS10, DRM 3.42.0, 5.4.0-84-generic, LLVM 12.0.1)
Platform #1: AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing
 `-- Device #0: Ellesmere
```

For some reason, I can compile and run OpenCL programs just fine when I specify platform 1, device 0. However, if I specify device 0, platform 0 I get this (runtime) error:

```
fatal error: cannot open file '/usr/local//usr/lib/clc/polaris10-amdgcn-mesa-mesa3d.bc': No such file or directory
```

The path is obviously incorrect, as it should be `/usr/lib/clc/polaris10-amdgcn-mesa-mesa3d.bc` (I checked and the file is actually present there).

Full output of `clinfo` also shows this error under `CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG`

```
clinfo 
Number of platforms                               2
  Platform Name                                   Clover
  Platform Vendor                                 Mesa
  Platform Version                                OpenCL 1.1 Mesa 21.3.0-devel (git-138463d 2021-09-12 focal-oibaf-ppa)
  Platform Profile                                FULL_PROFILE
  Platform Extensions                             cl_khr_icd
  Platform Extensions function suffix             MESA

  Platform Name                                   AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing
  Platform Vendor                                 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
  Platform Version                                OpenCL 2.1 AMD-APP (3302.5)
  Platform Profile                                FULL_PROFILE
  Platform Extensions                             cl_khr_icd cl_amd_event_callback cl_amd_offline_devices 
  Platform Host timer resolution                  1ns
  Platform Extensions function suffix             AMD

  Platform Name                                   Clover
Number of devices                                 1
  Device Name                                     Radeon RX 580 Series (POLARIS10, DRM 3.42.0, 5.4.0-84-generic, LLVM 12.0.1)
  Device Vendor                                   AMD
  Device Vendor ID                                0x1002
  Device Version                                  OpenCL 1.1 Mesa 21.3.0-devel (git-138463d 2021-09-12 focal-oibaf-ppa)
  Driver Version                                  21.3.0-devel
  Device OpenCL C Version                         OpenCL C 1.1 
  Device Type                                     GPU
  Device Profile                                  FULL_PROFILE
  Device Available                                Yes
  Compiler Available                              Yes
  Max compute units                               36
  Max clock frequency                             1366MHz
  Max work item dimensions                        3
  Max work item sizes                             256x256x256
  Max work group size                             256
=== CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG ===
fatal error: cannot open file '/usr/local//usr/lib/clc/polaris10-amdgcn-mesa-mesa3d.bc': No such file or directory
  Preferred work group size multiple              <getWGsizes:1200: create kernel : error -46>
  Preferred / native vector sizes                 
    char                                                16 / 16      
    short                                                8 / 8       
    int                                                  4 / 4       
    long                                                 2 / 2       
    half                                                 0 / 0        (n/a)
    float                                                4 / 4       
    double                                               2 / 2        (cl_khr_fp64)
  Half-precision Floating-point support           (n/a)
  Single-precision Floating-point support         (core)
    Denormals                                     No
    Infinity and NANs                             Yes
    Round to nearest                              Yes
    Round to zero                                 No
    Round to infinity                             No
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add               No
    Support is emulated in software               No
    Correctly-rounded divide and sqrt operations  No
  Double-precision Floating-point support         (cl_khr_fp64)
    Denormals                                     Yes
    Infinity and NANs                             Yes
    Round to nearest                              Yes
    Round to zero                                 Yes
    Round to infinity                             Yes
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add               Yes
    Support is emulated in software               No
  Address bits                                    64, Little-Endian
  Global memory size                              16784949248 (15.63GiB)
  Error Correction support                        No
  Max memory allocation                           6871947673 (6.4GiB)
  Unified memory for Host and Device              No
  Minimum alignment for any data type             128 bytes
  Alignment of base address                       32768 bits (4096 bytes)
  Global Memory cache type                        None
  Image support                                   No
  Local memory type                               Local
  Local memory size                               32768 (32KiB)
  Max number of constant args                     16
  Max constant buffer size                        67108864 (64MiB)
  Max size of kernel argument                     1024
  Queue properties                                
    Out-of-order execution                        No
    Profiling                                     Yes
  Profiling timer resolution                      0ns
  Execution capabilities                          
    Run OpenCL kernels                            Yes
    Run native kernels                            No
  Device Extensions                               cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_int64_base_atomics cl_khr_int64_extended_atomics cl_khr_fp64 cl_khr_extended_versioning

  Platform Name                                   AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing
Number of devices                                 1
  Device Name                                     Ellesmere
  Device Vendor                                   Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
  Device Vendor ID                                0x1002
  Device Version                                  OpenCL 2.0 AMD-APP (3302.5)
  Driver Version                                  3302.5 (PAL,HSAIL)
  Device OpenCL C Version                         OpenCL C 2.0 
  Device Type                                     GPU
  Device Board Name (AMD)                         Radeon RX 580 Series
  Device Topology (AMD)                           PCI-E, 07:00.0
  Device Profile                                  FULL_PROFILE
  Device Available                                Yes
  Compiler Available                              Yes
  Linker Available                                Yes
  Max compute units                               36
  SIMD per compute unit (AMD)                     4
  SIMD width (AMD)                                16
  SIMD instruction width (AMD)                    1
  Max clock frequency                             1366MHz
  Graphics IP (AMD)                               8.0
  Device Partition                                (core)
    Max number of sub-devices                     36
    Supported partition types                     None
    Supported affinity domains                    (n/a)
  Max work item dimensions                        3
  Max work item sizes                             1024x1024x1024
  Max work group size                             256
  Preferred work group size (AMD)                 256
  Max work group size (AMD)                       1024
  Preferred work group size multiple              64
  Wavefront width (AMD)                           64
  Preferred / native vector sizes                 
    char                                                 4 / 4       
    short                                                2 / 2       
    int                                                  1 / 1       
    long                                                 1 / 1       
    half                                                 1 / 1        (cl_khr_fp16)
    float                                                1 / 1       
    double                                               1 / 1        (cl_khr_fp64)
  Half-precision Floating-point support           (cl_khr_fp16)
    Denormals                                     No
    Infinity and NANs                             No
    Round to nearest                              No
    Round to zero                                 No
    Round to infinity                             No
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add               No
    Support is emulated in software               No
  Single-precision Floating-point support         (core)
    Denormals                                     No
    Infinity and NANs                             Yes
    Round to nearest                              Yes
    Round to zero                                 Yes
    Round to infinity                             Yes
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add               Yes
    Support is emulated in software               No
    Correctly-rounded divide and sqrt operations  Yes
  Double-precision Floating-point support         (cl_khr_fp64)
    Denormals                                     Yes
    Infinity and NANs                             Yes
    Round to nearest                              Yes
    Round to zero                                 Yes
    Round to infinity                             Yes
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add               Yes
    Support is emulated in software               No
  Address bits                                    64, Little-Endian
  Global memory size                              8589934592 (8GiB)
  Global free memory (AMD)                        8323072 (7.938GiB)
  Global memory channels (AMD)                    8
  Global memory banks per channel (AMD)           4
  Global memory bank width (AMD)                  256 bytes
  Error Correction support                        No
  Max memory allocation                           7073274265 (6.587GiB)
  Unified memory for Host and Device              No
  Shared Virtual Memory (SVM) capabilities        (core)
    Coarse-grained buffer sharing                 Yes
    Fine-grained buffer sharing                   Yes
    Fine-grained system sharing                   No
    Atomics                                       No
  Minimum alignment for any data type             128 bytes
  Alignment of base address                       2048 bits (256 bytes)
  Preferred alignment for atomics                 
    SVM                                           0 bytes
    Global                                        0 bytes
    Local                                         0 bytes
  Max size for global variable                    6365946624 (5.929GiB)
  Preferred total size of global vars             8589934592 (8GiB)
  Global Memory cache type                        Read/Write
  Global Memory cache size                        16384 (16KiB)
  Global Memory cache line size                   64 bytes
  Image support                                   Yes
    Max number of samplers per kernel             16
    Max size for 1D images from buffer            442079641 pixels
    Max 1D or 2D image array size                 2048 images
    Base address alignment for 2D image buffers   256 bytes
    Pitch alignment for 2D image buffers          256 pixels
    Max 2D image size                             16384x16384 pixels
    Max 3D image size                             2048x2048x2048 pixels
    Max number of read image args                 128
    Max number of write image args                64
    Max number of read/write image args           64
  Max number of pipe args                         16
  Max active pipe reservations                    16
  Max pipe packet size                            2778306969 (2.587GiB)
  Local memory type                               Local
  Local memory size                               65536 (64KiB)
  Local memory syze per CU (AMD)                  65536 (64KiB)
  Local memory banks (AMD)                        32
  Max number of constant args                     8
  Max constant buffer size                        7073274265 (6.587GiB)
  Preferred constant buffer size (AMD)            16384 (16KiB)
  Max size of kernel argument                     1024
  Queue properties (on host)                      
    Out-of-order execution                        No
    Profiling                                     Yes
  Queue properties (on device)                    
    Out-of-order execution                        Yes
    Profiling                                     Yes
    Preferred size                                262144 (256KiB)
    Max size                                      8388608 (8MiB)
  Max queues on device                            1
  Max events on device                            1024
  Prefer user sync for interop                    Yes
  Number of P2P devices (AMD)                     0
  P2P devices (AMD)                               <printDeviceInfo:147: get number of CL_DEVICE_P2P_DEVICES_AMD : error -30>
  Profiling timer resolution                      1ns
  Profiling timer offset since Epoch (AMD)        1631422930353671212ns (Sun Sep 12 07:02:10 2021)
  Execution capabilities                          
    Run OpenCL kernels                            Yes
    Run native kernels                            No
    Thread trace supported (AMD)                  Yes
    Number of async queues (AMD)                  4
    Max real-time compute queues (AMD)            1
    Max real-time compute units (AMD)             0
  printf() buffer size                            4194304 (4MiB)
  Built-in kernels                                (n/a)
  Device Extensions                               cl_khr_fp64 cl_amd_fp64 cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_int64_base_atomics cl_khr_int64_extended_atomics cl_khr_3d_image_writes cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_fp16 cl_khr_gl_sharing cl_khr_gl_depth_images cl_amd_device_attribute_query cl_amd_vec3 cl_amd_printf cl_amd_media_ops cl_amd_media_ops2 cl_amd_popcnt cl_khr_image2d_from_buffer cl_khr_subgroups cl_khr_gl_event cl_khr_depth_images cl_khr_mipmap_image cl_khr_mipmap_image_writes cl_amd_copy_buffer_p2p 


NULL platform behavior
  clGetPlatformInfo(NULL, CL_PLATFORM_NAME, ...)  No platform
  clGetDeviceIDs(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, ...)   No platform
  clCreateContext(NULL, ...) [default]            No platform
  clCreateContext(NULL, ...) [other]              Success [MESA]
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_DEFAULT)  Success (1)
    Platform Name                                 Clover
    Device Name                                   Radeon RX 580 Series (POLARIS10, DRM 3.42.0, 5.4.0-84-generic, LLVM 12.0.1)
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU)  No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU)  Success (1)
    Platform Name                                 Clover
    Device Name                                   Radeon RX 580 Series (POLARIS10, DRM 3.42.0, 5.4.0-84-generic, LLVM 12.0.1)
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ACCELERATOR)  No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CUSTOM)  No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL)  Success (1)
    Platform Name                                 Clover
    Device Name                                   Radeon RX 580 Series (POLARIS10, DRM 3.42.0, 5.4.0-84-generic, LLVM 12.0.1)
```

Any idea how to fix the path? I guess I could symlink `/usr/` to `/usr/local/usr/` but that seems like a bad idea.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm running into the same thing.

Comment: Unfortunately, not. I'm using platform 1 now, which works okay in my case.

Comment: Symlink seems to work.  https://einsteinathome.org/content/2021-08-16-ubuntu-updates-mesa-and-ocl-divers-still-errors-package